# "unresolved variable or type google"

Tags: google-maps-api-3, webstorm

Using Google Maps API, WebStorm is telling me that `google` is unresolved.  I have added the library in the `Languages & Frameworks` setting but it persists.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[google-maps](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/google-maps) is not the right library, please use [googlemaps](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/googlemaps/) instead. You can download it via `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`, or install in your project via npm (`npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev`)

[image]

Comment: I added it in PhpStorm using the option _Download Library_ and half of the warnings are gone, but I still receive it for `DirectionsRenderer` | `DirectionsService` | `Geocoder` | `Map` | `LatLng`. What am I mssing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to suppress warning.

Check this please :
[How do I resolve JetBrains WebStorm 'Unresolved variable webServ' warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992472/how-do-i-resolve-jetbrains-webstorm-unresolved-variable-webserv-warning)