# How do I resolve JetBrains WebStorm 'Unresolved variable webServ' warning?

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I'm utilizing [WebStorm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) for node.js development and I'm trying to cleanup all  the WebStorm warnings and errors.

The remaining error is a 'Unresolved variable webServ' warning, but the use of the req.params.webServ is correct.

I don't want to just remove the WebStorm 'Unresolved variable...' warning.

How do I resolve this WebStorm IDE warning?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `webServ` is not defined anywhere in your code (except for root path string passed to `delete()`), it can't be resolved using static code analysis. You can suppress such warnings for statement using comments (hit `Alt+Enter`, then hit `Right`, choose *Suppress for statement*).
See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17419#comment=27-1058451, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206349469-disable-unresolved-variable-on-json-object-received-by-ajax-call for other possible workarounds

Comment: For others reading this "then hit Right" literally means hit the right arrow key! The aforementioned will add a comment, which tells WebStorm to ignore a specific rule in the next line.